# Tomcat SSO across subdomains

Tags: session, tomcat, single-sign-on

I have a tomcat server serving multiple web applications. They leverage tomcat SSO to seamlessly login the user. However, this does not seem to work if the applications have different sub domains.

Is there a way to get tomcat SSO to work across applications residing on same server but served under different sub domains.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `cookieDomain` attribute on the single signon Valve (see http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/valve.html#Single_Sign_On_Valve) to the common root domain and see if this works: if you're trying to single sign on to *a.example.com* and *b.example.com* try setting the SSO cookie to *example.com* or *.example.com*.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a corporate environment you could use Kerberos to perform SSO across domains.